# Codeigniter: Make uploads accessible

Tags: codeigniter, upload, codeigniter-3

I'm using the upload class to allow users uploading file to the server.

Those files (e.g. profile images) should be accessible in the browser. Right now, the files stored under `/application/uploads` which of course cannot be accessed via browser.

Is there a way to make those uploaded files accessible via htaccess?

The only way I can think of, would be moving the files into the `/public` folder after being uploaded to `/application/uploads`

What's the best case to handle this?

Comment: best case is move it from the application folder, put it at same level of application

Answer (score 0):

your folder structure should be like :

```
---application
   --- controllers
   --- helpers
   --- views
---asset
---system
---uploads
```

And Whenever you want to fetch/show image use

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'); ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the files in outside i.e. in public/uploads folder
2. Create .htaccess file in that folder
3. Add following line to .htaccess to secure the folder

   Options -Indexes